# Is it ppossiible to change default kubelet port 10250

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes cluster is running in a restricted environment where we are unable to open ports as we want(only a range of ports are allowed for customized use), Some how I have started the kubernetes API server(6443 by default) on a allowed port using the config options with 'kubeadm init' , is there any way to change the default port of 10250 (kubelet API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubelet port can be changed from default `10250` by passing an argument to `KubeletConfiguration`:

| Field | Description |
| --- | --- |
| port int32 | port is the port for the Kubelet to serve on. The port number must be between 1 and 65535, inclusive. Default: 10250 |

- --> *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Config api: KubeletConfiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/#kubelet-config-k8s-io-v1beta1-KubeletConfiguration)*

By default it resides in:

- *`/var/lib/kubelet/config`*

---

For this configuration to be available from the start (from `kubeadm init ...`) I'd check following documentation:

> #### Configure kubelets using kubeadm
>
> It is possible to configure the kubelet that kubeadm will start if a custom [KubeletConfiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/) API object is passed with a configuration file like so `kubeadm ... --config some-config-file.yaml`.
>
> By calling `kubeadm config print init-defaults --component-configs KubeletConfiguration` you can see all the default values for this structure.
>
> It is also possible to apply instance-specific patches over the base KubeletConfiguration. Have a look at [Customizing the kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags#customizing-the-kubelet) for more details.
>
> > *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: Control plane flags: Customizing the kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags#customizing-the-kubelet)*

Answer (score 0):

The port is set in the  kube-apiserver.yaml by the option

```
- --secure-port=6443
```

Changing this value and restarting the api server should solve your problem.

When creating a new cluster you can use the option

```
--apiserver-bind-port <port>
```

to start the api-server on a different port